# Make arrays with arrays

Tags: arrays, drupal

I would like to create a lot of arrays in my Drupal folder. But I'm not sure how to do this. Basically, it's always the same structure.

```
$form['actions']['saveasdraft']['#type'] = 'submit';
$form['actions']['saveasdraft']['#access'] = true;
$form['actions']['saveasdraft']['#value'] = 'Save as Draft';
$form['actions']['saveasdraft']['#weight'] = 11;
$form['actions']['saveasdraft']['#submit'][0] = 'node_fiche_form_submit'; 

$form['actions']['saveascurrent']['#type'] = 'submit';
$form['actions']['saveascurrent']['#access'] = true;
$form['actions']['saveascurrent']['#value'] = 'Save as New version';
$form['actions']['saveascurrent']['#weight'] = 12;
$form['actions']['saveascurrent']['#submit'][0] = 'node_fiche_form_submit'; 

...
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'correct' way to do it is like this (see [Drupal coding standards](http://drupal.org/coding-standards#array)):

```
$form['action']['saveasdraft'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#access' => TRUE,
  '#value' => 'Save as Draft',
  // etc...
);

$form['action']['saveascurrent'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#access' => TRUE,
  '#value' => 'Save as New version',
  // etc...
);
```

That's the way Drupal core modules do it (and all contributed modules that I've ever seen).

**EDIT**

If you're worried about repeating code the best you're going to be able to do is set up some defaults...should save a few hundred lines :)

```
$defaults = array('#type' => 'submit', '#access' => TRUE, /* etc... */);

$form['action']['saveasdraft'] = $defaults + array(
  '#value' => 'Save as Draft'
);

$form['action']['saveascurrent'] = $defaults + array(
  '#value' => 'Save as New version'
);
```

Hope that makes sense

Comment: Correct! I forgot. But is there a way to add 100+ arrays with as less code as possible?

Comment: Yes, it does :-) Thanks a lot! I which I could vote more then once ;-)

Comment: Great answer, but nothing is showing up. I miss some kind of return I guess... Could you help me out?

Comment: It might be a good idea to post your full code (or as much as you can fit!) on a new question...there's not much room to discuss in these comments and you'll get the benefit of a lot more people looking at the question :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to employ a rule of DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself). You can do it eg. by creating function that will return proper element to be entered into bigger array like that:

```
function form_element($value, $weight, $type = 'submit', $access = true,
    $submit = 'node_fiche_form_submit') {
    return array(
        '#type' => $type,
        '#access' => $access,
        '#value' => $value,
        '#weight' => $weight,
        '#submit' => array($submit),
    );
};
```

and you can then use it like that:

```
$form['actions']['saveasdraft'] = form_element('Save as Draft', 11);
$form['actions']['saveascurrent'] = form_element('Save as New version', 12);
// ...and so on
```

See [this codepad](http://codepad.org/xXHNZufQ) for a proof.

PS. Of course you should invent some more meaningful and less-conflicting name for the helper function, but the approach is one of the shortest.

Comment: Great tip! Thanks! Why is the `'#submit' => array($submit)` an array?

Comment: @Michiel: The `#submit` key is always passed as an array. You actually pass it as such in your original code, denoted by the `[0]` at the end  of the element: `$form['actions']['saveascurrent']['#submit'][0]`

Comment: @Michiel: Clive is right - it is because you have requested `$form['actions']['saveascurrent']['#submit'][0] = 'node_fiche_form_submit';` and `[0]` generally means that `$form['actions']['saveascurrent']['#submit']` is an array with at least one element.